# How do I yield a custom object from a native Python coroutine?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

When using generator functions to implement coroutines (as it was common in Python 3.4 and earlier), it was easy to yield custom objects:

```py
class CustomObject:
    pass

def coroutine2():
    yield CustomObject()
    return 'the result'

def coroutine1():
    return (yield from coroutine2())

it = coroutine1()
while True:
    try:
        io_req = next(it)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        assert exc.value == 'the result'
        break
    assert isinstance(io_req, CustomObject)
```

How do I do the same thing using native co-routines? The naive approach fails, because there seems to be no equivalent to `yield` (`await` replaces `yield from`), and `yield` itself is not allowed in native coroutine:

```py
class CustomObject:
    pass

async def coroutine2():
    # This gives: TypeError: CustomObject can't be used in 'await' expression
    #await CustomObject()
    
    # And this gives: TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression
    #yield CustomObject()

    # So what needs to go here?
    magic_keyword CustomObject()

    return 'the result'

async def coroutine1():
    return await coroutine2()

it = coroutine1().__await__()
while True:
    try:
        io_req = next(it)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        assert exc.value == 'the result'
        break
    assert isinstance(io_req, CustomObject)
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but `yield from MyAwaitable().__await__()` ?

Comment: Wait do you think `magic_keyword=await` is not correct? The documentation clearly states "coroutine or awaitable (i.e. has an `__await__` attribute that is an iterator)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Neither `yield` nor `yield from` are allowed in coroutines, this gives a syntax error.

Comment: Your code in `my_coroutine` implies that statements will follow the "magic_keyword" line of code.  But your question asks how to *return* a coroutine.  You do that the way you always return things: with a return statement.  Code that follows will, of course, be unreachable.  Do you mean to ask how to *yield* a coroutine?  Do that with a yield statement.  I'm not aware of other possibilities.  Can you explain exactly what you want this magic keyword to do?

Comment: @PaulCornelius That' a good catch, thank you. I am not sure what the right verb is to describe what I meant. What I want is control over the value of `my_coroutine()`. If  `my_coroutine` was a regular function, this would be the value specified in the functions `return` statement. If `my_coroutine` was a generator function, this would be the value specified in the functions `yield` statement. I do not how to call it for the case where `my_coroutine` is a co-routine. Note that `yield` statements are no longer allowed in coroutines (this gives a syntax error), so using `yield` is not the answer.

Comment: @MegaIng Using `await` for `magic_keyword` gives a `TypeError`. I've extended my question to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
import asyncio


class MyAwaitable:
    async def generate_answer(self):
        return 42

    def __await__(self):
        return self.generate_answer().__await__()


async def my_coroutine():
    res = await MyAwaitable()
    print("got:", res)


asyncio.run(my_coroutine())
```

Comment: This runs, yes, but it doesn't accomplish the objective since it does not actually construct the objects that `asyncio.run` iterates over (but instead uses `async def` to construct an empty iterator).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments! They helped me find the right solution myself.

The important point is that `await` does not directly replace `yield from`. In `yield from exp`, `exp` must be an iterator. However, in `await exp`, `exp` must be an object with a `__await__` method that returns an iterator.

I think therefore the following is the right way to yield a custom object:

```py
class CustomObject:
    pass

class CustomAwaitable:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c
    def __await__(self):
        yield self.c
    
async def coroutine2():
    await CustomAwaitable(CustomObject())
    return 'the result'

async def coroutine1():
    return await coroutine2()

it = coroutine1().__await__()
while True:
    try:
        io_req = next(it)
    except StopIteration as exc:
        assert exc.value == 'the result'
        break
    assert isinstance(io_req, CustomObject)
```